# why i add 1 to the variable but it adds "2" every time?

Tags: javascript

In the code below I want to add 1 to the `page` variable but every time I click on next button it adds 2 to the variable.

[Code in Codepen](https://codepen.io/Treebeard/pen/MWJPjMe)

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slides');
var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
var page = 0;

function Swiper(page) {
  if (page > slides.length) page = 0;
  if (page < 0) page = slides.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  slides[page].classList.add('active');
  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove('active-dot');
  }
  dots[page].classList.add('active-dot');
  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove('active-dot');
  }
  dots[page].classList.add('active-dot');
}

function Slider(slider) {
  console.log(page)
  console.log(slider)
  Swiper(page += slider);
  console.log(page += slider)
}

function currentSlide(pagination) {
  Swiper(page = pagination);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Raleway;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* body>h1,body>h2,body>h3,body>h4,body>h5,body>h6,body>p{
     padding-left: 16px;
      .btnload:hover{
     background-color: #4169E1;
} */

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-25 {
  flex: 25%;
}

.col-50 {
  flex: 50%;
}

.col-75 {
  flex: 75%;
}

.col-100 {
  flex: 100%;
}

button,
input {
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  animation: slide 0.4s ease;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.slides .page-number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  color: white;
}

.slides .desc {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 310px;
  left: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container a {
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.616);
}

.container #right-slide {
  right: 0px;
}

.container #left-slide {
  left: 0px;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 380px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pagination .dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.pagination .dot:hover {
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
}

.dot {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.active-dot {
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
}

.no-active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slides active">
    <div class="page-number">1/4</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="desc">Caption One</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slides">
    <div class="page-number">2/4</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="desc">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slides">
    <div class="page-number">3/4</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="desc">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slides">
    <div class="page-number">4/4</div>
    <img src="Images/img_mountains_wide.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="desc">Caption Four</div>
  </div>

  <a onclick="Slider(-1)" id="left-slide" href="#">&#10094;</a>
  <a onclick="Slider(+1)" id="right-slide" href="#">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="dot dot-color active-dot" onclick="currentSlide(0, event)"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-color" onclick="currentSlide(1, event)"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-color" onclick="currentSlide(2, event)"></span>
  <span class="dot dot-color" onclick="currentSlide(3, event)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are adding it twice - once in `Swiper(page += slider)` and once in `console.log(page += slider)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>  Swiper(page += slider);
>  console.log(page += slider)
> ```

First you add `slider` to `page` (updating the value of `page`) and pass the result to `Swiper`.

Then you add `slider` to  (the new value of) `page` (updating the value of `page` **again**) and pass the result to `console.log`.

---

As a rule of thumb, combining operations that modify variables with operations that pass them to functions is a good way to confuse yourself.

You might want to split out the actions for clarity.

```
page += slider;
Swiper(page);
console.log(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because of this line `console.log(page += slider)`

It makes the page increase 2 times

```
function Slider(slider) {
    console.log(page)
    console.log(slider)
    Swiper(page += slider);
    console.log(page += slider) // <<<--------------- This line
}
```